# How to simplify this code in Javascript via function chaining?

Tags: javascript, arrays, simplify, method-chaining, simplification

I would to know how to simplify theses function calls by chaining them. Is there a way to chain forEach, push, destructuring array and map.

```
 let selectorsForLoader = ['a', 'b'];
 let loadingElements = [];
    selectorsForLoader.forEach(selector => {
      loadingElements.push(...Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)));
    });
    let loaders = loadingElements.map(loadingElement => {
      loadingElement.doSomething();
    });
```

Here is an example of what I mean by function chaining:

```
   food.map(item => item.type)
  .reduce((result, fruit) => {
    result.push(fruit);
    return [...new Set(result)];
  }, []);
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're trying to achieve. Have you been given advice that you don't understand how to implement or something?

Comment: I clarifyed the question.

Comment: Which of the two snippets are you asking about? I cannot see how they are related.

Comment: You are looking for `flatMap`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There you go:

```
['a', 'b'].flatMap(selector => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)));
  }).forEach(loadingElement => {
    loadingElement.doSomething();
  });
```

By the way, that "example" you gave *should be written* like this:

```
new Set(food.map(item => item.type));
```